# Is .join() being used incorrectly or is there other mistake? (python)

Tags: python, list

am trying to build a function for a word guessing game, where the guessed letter will be displayed alongside blank space for yet-to-be guessed letters. In the following code I get type error, which says the guessed letter, a string, can't be concatenated in the list. Is this because of .join() being used incorrectly? Thanks!

```
import random

Dictionary = {"fruits": "papaya", "buildings": "apartment", "mammal": "horse"}


def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_word = random.choice(list(Dictionary.items()))
    print("Hint: " + hint)
    for letter in chosen_word:
        blank = []
        blank.append("_")
        print("".join(blank), end="")
    player_guess = input("\nPlease guess a letter between A-Z\n")
    if player_guess in chosen_word:
        letter = chosen_word.find(player_guess)
        print("".join((blank)[:letter]+player_guess+blank[letter+1:]), end="")


choose_word()
```

Comment: `join` looks right. But you can't do `list + str`. Try `list + [str]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.  You need to move `blank = []` out of the loop, otherwise you reset the list every time.  Your second `join` call is not correct, but not because of `join`, it's because you're "adding" three things here: a list, a string, and a list, and that's not allowed.  You COULD turn them all into lists by making alist of the guess:

```
    print("".join(blank[:letter]+[player_guess]+blank[letter+1:]))
```

But that's not really what you want, is it?  Don't you want to fill in the propert letters?  Here is code that plays one round.  It will be up to you to have it play multiple rounds.

```
import random

Dictionary = {"fruits": "papaya", "buildings": "apartment", "mammal": "horse"}

def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_word = random.choice(list(Dictionary.items()))
    print("Hint:", hint)
    blank = []
    for letter in chosen_word:
        blank.append("_")
    print(" ".join(blank), end="")
    player_guess = input("\nPlease guess a letter between A-Z\n")
    if player_guess in chosen_word:
        letter = chosen_word.find(player_guess)
        blank[letter] = player_guess
        print(" ".join(blank))

choose_word()
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
Hint: fruits
_ _ _ _ _ _
Please guess a letter between A-Z
a
_ a _ _ _ _
timr@tims-gram:~/src$
```

Comment: @ Tim Roberts I added a while loop to in order to display correctly guessed repeat letter, and use blank[letter] = player_guess. But I got an index out of range error.

Comment: Here's what I mean;  
def choose_word():  
    hint, chosen_word = random.choice(list(Dictionary.items()))  
    print("Hint: " + hint)
    for letter in chosen_word:
        blank = []
        blank.append("_")
        print("".join(blank), end="")
    player_guess = input("\nPlease guess a letter between A-Z\n")
    letter = 0
    if player_guess in chosen_word:
        while chosen_word.find(player_guess, letter) != -1:
            letter = chosen_word.find(player_guess, letter)
            blank[letter] = player_guess
            letter += 1
    print("".join(blank))

Comment: apology for the messed up formatting, couldn't figure out the insert line break formatting rule :(

Comment: You can't format in comments.  You will either have to edit your original question or submit a new question.